# What's wrong with this Winform C# code? It will run fine in Windows, but in mono(Linux), will throw a NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, sql, nullreferenceexception

The error is:
`System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` 
I know that this error occurs when an object was used but was not initialize or being initialized but was later declared null but was nevertheless being accessed that caused the exception. But I can't figure out where the offending object was so I can correct it myself. The error will show after I selected a string from a Listbox control a second time. At first it will work and then if I select another item a second time the program will quit abruptly, the error will show at the command line in Linux.

I can show the complete error after running mono `win_binary_file` if needed.

After debugging, I've found this offending code that will throw the NullReferenceException:

```
public void fListItems(DataGridView datagridview1, string param_name)
    {
        NpgsqlDataAdapter dr = default(NpgsqlDataAdapter);
        DataSet ds;
        string sql;
        NpgsqlConnection dbcon;
        string connectionstr = "SERVER=" + DataBaseHost + ";DATABASE=" + DatabaseName + ";USER ID=" + DatabaseUser + ";PASSWORD=" + DatabasePassword + ";pooling=true; port=" + DatabasePort;
        dbcon = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionstr);
        try
        {
            sql = "SELECT * FROM purchase_order" +                     
           " WHERE purchase_request_num= '" + param_name + "' ORDER BY id ASC; ";                
            dbcon.Open();
            ds = new DataSet("purchase_order");
            dr = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
            dr.SelectCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, dbcon);
            dr.Fill(ds, "purchase_order");
            datagridview1.DataSource = ds.Tables["purchase_order"];
        } 
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            dbcon.Close();
        }
    }
```

This code will call the function above:

```
private void listboxPR_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        string prnumberSelect;
        if (varname == 180)
        {
            //Somecode here for condition varname=180
            prnumberSelect = listboxPR.Text.ToString();
            Class1.fListItems(DataGridRequests, prnumberSelect);
        }
        else
        {
            prnumberSelect = listboxPR.Text.ToString();
            Class1.fListItems(DataGridRequests, prnumberSelect);
        }
        Cursor = Cursors.Default;

    }
```

The complete error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at purchase_requisition.frmmain.DataGridRequests_SelectionChanged (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnSelectionChanged (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SetSelectedRowCore (Int32 rowIndex, Boolean selected) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SetSelectedRowCoreInternal (Int32 rowIndex, Boolean selected) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView:SetSelectedRowCoreInternal (int,bool)
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewBand.set_Selected (Boolean value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow.set_Selected (Boolean value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.ClearSelection () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.MoveCurrentCell (Int32 x, Int32 y, Boolean select, Boolean isControl, Boolean isShift, Boolean scroll) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.ClearBinding () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.set_DataSource (System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView:set_DataSource (object)
  at purchase_requisition.dbquery.PRMonitoringGrid (System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView DatagridRequests, System.String Purchase_Number) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at purchase_requisition.frmmain.listboxPR_SelectedIndexChanged (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.OnItemClick (Int32 index) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.OnMouseUpLB (System.Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnMouseUp (System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmLButtonUp (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlWindowTarget.OnMessage (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc (IntPtr hWnd, Msg msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: which line throws the exception?

Comment: I can't debug it in Linux so I am not sure where the the line that throws the error, but I am sure it was that function.

Comment: Can't you log the whole callstack?

Comment: Logging the error would be a good choice

Comment: Sql injection hazard ahead. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: While at it, you should stop writing SQL injection prone code. That is a far bigger concern that the NRE

Comment: Added the whole error @bgusach, yes ATC, I am using parameterized queries, but I am still at development stage, I use it to easily log my sql queries, besides this is an inhouse project.

Comment: @RemusRusanu I am aware of it, as mentioned, this is an inhouse project and will be using parameterized queries. I am using it for the meantime to easily log my sql query errors.

Comment: Can you write to a logfile? If so, use "old school" debugging: add a lot of log messages to show the values of the various variables and how far you got in your method before it broke. Else use a lot of "if something is null show a messagebox"

Comment: You can obviously debug it if you check MonoDevelop and Mono guides.

Comment: The top-most "at" in the stack trace shows the method in which the exception occurs. Check the `DataGridRequests_SelectionChanged` event handler.

Comment: I'm guessing that it's probably somewhere in the line that builds the connection string. Print the values of all those members, individually, before you try to use them.

Comment: Ok, @C.Evenhuis. thank you guys, will try using a logfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that the function fListItems() is not at fault at all. It was the DatagridREquests_SelectionChanged event's code that triggers the exception. I transferred the offending code under the listboxPR_SelectedIndexChanged event, because what I need is to get data from the datagrid after it was populated by the function fListItems().

```
private void listboxPR_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    string prnumberSelect;
    if (varname == 180)
    {
        //Somecode here for condition varname=180
        prnumberSelect = listboxPR.Text.ToString();
        Class1.fListItems(DataGridRequests, prnumberSelect);
        //Transferred code from DatagridRequests_SelectionChanged event
        if (DataGridRequests.RowCount > 0 ) {
            intVar1 = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridRequests.CurrentRow.Cells["column"].Value);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        prnumberSelect = listboxPR.Text.ToString();
        Class1.fListItems(DataGridRequests, prnumberSelect);
        if (DataGridRequests.RowCount > 0 ) {
            intVar1 = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridRequests.CurrentRow.Cells["column"].Value);
        }
    }
    Cursor = Cursors.Default;

}
```

Thank you guys for helping me....